# Setting height on side-by-side WPF controls

Tags: wpf, height

I have two WPF borders, each of which contains some content, which I wish to display side-by-side, and I would like the following height rules to apply:

(1) The height of the control inside the left-hand border will determine the height of both controls.
(2) If the height of the control inside the left-hand border is less than 200, then both borders should have a height of 200 (this is a minimum height).
(3) If the height of the control inside the left-hand border is greater than 200, then both borders should be set to the height the left-hand border would take if the right-hand border did not exist. The right-hand border will then stretch or be squashed to match what the left-hand border desires.

Is this possible in XAML, or do I have to use some code? And if so, what code would work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind your right hand border's height to the left one's `ActualHeight` and set both borders to have a `MinHeight` of 200

```
<Border x:Name="leftBorder" MinHeight="200"></Border>
<Border MinHeight="200" Height="{Binding ElementName=leftBorder, Path=ActualHeight}"></Border>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. It works up to a point, but there is an issue if the content of the left border grows (above 200) and then later shrinks. The two borders expand correctly as the content grows, but once the content shrinks again (which means the left border's height should shrink), the two borders do not shrink, they just keep their existing size.

Comment: The best thing in that case is to set your border to VerticalAlignment=Top. This pushes the bottom edge of the border up to the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 0):

for doing something like this you need a converter which means that you have to use some code .
set height of both left and right border to :

```
Height="{Binding ElementName=leftcontrol,Path=ActualHeight,Converter=developedConverter}"
```

and then put your logic for border's heights in the converter body.

Comment: So the idea is that I use developedConverter to convert the content size into an ideal border size? That would work I guess, for example by adding some fixed known constant to the content size, but it sounds like a bit of a fudge when ordinary the WPF layout manager can do this job for me (i.e. set the border to the correct size for its content). Any thoughts?

Comment: yes if it's just the size of content inside the border you don't have to use the converter ,but I thought you have a logic which can't be done by using only WPF layout manager . like he comparisons that you have .